# How to send the IP of a router from another via dyndns?

Tags: networking, router, switch, dynamic-dns, dynamic-ip

I have a main ZyXEL router with integrated modem so it is connected to the [ISP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Service_Provider) directly via ADSL. I have a [DVR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_video_recorder) in LAN1 and I want to access it remotely via Internet.

I configured everything, set the dyndns settings in the ZyXEL router, everything works properly my only problem is that the router can't synchronize the IP through dyndns reliably. It works (updates the IP at [No-IP](http://www.noip.com)) for 2-3 days, but after it, the router never synchronizes, so when the dynamic IP adress changes I can't access the system remotely, because I can't find out the IP remotely.

I think there is a problem with tha ISP provided routers dyndns functionality. Because the router is integrated with the modem, I can't omit it so my first idea was to put another router that works properly with dyndns, to LAN2 and it will send the IP. The problem is that router's IP is the local IP assigned by the main router, something like `192.168.1.102`.

Will it work anyway? Is there a way I could use this second router to send the main routers IP via dyndns? Can I do this if I use the second router as a switch?

[image: The setup]

Comment: There must be something wrong with your set up, or your ISP. I too use dyndns, I have installed it on a Linux pc behind my router, so this pc has a private IP address (192.168.xxx.zzz), and it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

> Will it work anyway?

Yes, having a device behind the original router should still update the No-IP service correctly.

> Is there a way I could use this second router to send the main routers IP via dyndns?

This should be done automatically. The No-IP Client works by querying the server and the server will update the IP address with the address that the query comes from, in this case this is the external IP address of your home connection

> Can I do this if I use the second router as a switch?

Yes you can.

Comment: This is not an answer for the question. I didn't asked about port forwarding or how to access the DVR, all of these are working properly. DynDNS is not about typing a hostname instead of an IP, it's about having a fix address instead of an IP that always changes (thus I can't find it out remotely). My question was how can I use a second router to send the IP through dyndns, so I can acces the system remotely again. I have to use a second router because the main is integrated with the model so I can't omit it.

Comment: Apologies, The original question was not worded / formatted to be easy to read. Does your ZyXEL router have a DynDNS client ? Do you have a computer that's always on to run a DynDNS client on ?

Comment: Yes the original setup (that failed) used the ZyXEL's dyndns. Theres no PC on the system. Anyway I don't asked about how to fix this issue. **I am asking about how can I use a second router to achieve my goal.** This is what I asked in the title, that is the main question.

Comment: Ok, well the original question did not specify that the orignal setup used the ZyXELs dyndns client. I am trying to get the information I need to help you get to the resolution you want.

Comment: Not true, I told "router can't synchronize the IP through dyndns" this means that the router is the dyndns client. Anyway, that was just a misunderstanding. I appreciate your help, and your last edit contains helpful advices. Thank You. I will try them, and send a reply later. Also removed the -1.

Comment: I tried it out and it doesn't work. The second router connects succesfully with the No-IP service, but it sends the local address `192.168.1.103`. Could you show me the links or other refferences where does your information comes from?

Comment: Experience. It depends on how the DynDNS client works. Some work by sending the IP address that is currently on the device to the DynDNS provider. Others do it by a reverse lookup. It seems that your device does it the first way. Does your ZyXEL have the ability to pass through the public IP address to hte TP-Link ? Or does the DVR itself have the ability to do DynDNS ?